# How to properly join tables with a many to one relationship

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I have six tables

- The main table `Orders` is an encrypted table containing orders that customers have made.
- The second table is a hash table for the `Orders` table. `OrdersHash`.
- The remaining four tables are store tables that all have the same structure. `StoreA, StoreB, StoreC, & StoreD`.

  Orders Table

  orderId | rest of row...

  OrdersHash Table

  orderId | orderIdHash | rest of row..

  The four store tables all share this structure.

  orderIdHash | customerId | rest of row..

Using only the `customerId` I am trying to query the four store tables to see if any of the store tables contain the `customerId`. If the `customerId` is found on any of the four store tables I want to use the `orderIdHash` to get me back to the original `Orders` table and return the row for any orders that were found.

[image]

If I use a the customerId for Mike I would expect row 1 from the Orders table.

This is what I have tried so far.

```
"SELECT 

    o.dateShipped       AS orderShipped,
    o.shipped           AS shipped,
    o.recieved          AS recieved

    FROM Orders o

    JOIN OrdersHash oHash
        ON o.orderId = oHash.orderId
    JOIN StoreA a
        ON ohash.orderIdHash = a.orderIdHash
    JOIN StoreB b
        ON ohash.orderIdHash = b.orderIdHash
    JOIN StoreC c
        ON ohash.orderIdHash = c.orderIdHash
    JOIN StoreD d
        ON ohash.orderIdHash = d.orderIdHash

    WHERE
    a.customerId = :customerId1
    OR b.customerId = :customerId2
    OR c.customerId = :customerId3
    OR d.customerId = :customerId4";
```

**customerId 1,2,3,4 are all the same value.. I have to use a different name for binding in PDO.

This will return a result but it seems to return the same row from `Orders` for every row in a store with a matching `orderIdHash` when I just need the one record from the `Orders` table.

Thank you in advance for your help.

Comment: Just an idea - but if all the binds are the same value, why not just replace it by using `b.customerId = a.customerId` etc.

Comment: Not a bad idea, when I get the crux of this figured out I will look at that.

Comment: Why do you have multiple store tables, normally you would have 1 table and some form if store ID linking this to a Store table with the particular details.

Comment: Four vendors four tables.. It's what I was given to work with.

Comment: does orders contain 1 row per order? does ordershash contain 1 row per order? can an order be fulfilled by many stores? Sample data would help clarify,

Comment: yes one row per order on the orders table..

Comment: @P.Salmon The store tables may contain multiple rows with the same `orderIdHash` and have multiple `customerId's` belonging to different customers.

Comment: @P.Salmon Orders contains 1 row per order.  OrderHash is a mirror of Orders so it also has 1 row per order.  Each store can contribute to the single order.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems you probably want to `UNION` the store results and then `JOIN` that to the `Orders` table. By using `UNION` rather than `UNION ALL`, we can select only the distinct `orderIdHash` values, ensuring we only get one row for each `Order` in the result table. Something like this:

```
SELECT o.dateShipped       AS orderShipped,
       o.shipped           AS shipped,
       o.recieved          AS recieved
FROM (SELECT customerId, orderIdHash
      FROM (SELECT customerId, orderIdHash FROM StoreA
            UNION
            SELECT customerId, orderIdHash FROM StoreB
            UNION
            SELECT customerId, orderIdHash FROM StoreC
            UNION
            SELECT customerId, orderIdHash FROM StoreD
            ) stores
      WHERE customerId = :customerId) c
JOIN OrdersHash oHash ON oHash.orderIdHash = c.orderIdHash
JOIN Orders o ON o.orderId = oHash.orderId
```

Comment: Here's a demo which seems to show the correct results (at least, correct as I interpret your question) for each person in your sample data: https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/wnzqgdJkRZZYBneStnXhw1/0